# factoryboy not overriding django model properties

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

I'm trying to override a custom Django model property via `factory_boy` for testing purposes. But it seems like it is simply taking the default behavior of the model. is factory boy not able to change the default behaviour of custom attributes?

Here is a basic test I wrote:

**models.py**:

```
class Session(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return method_not_callable_in_testing()

def method_not_callable_in_testing():
    return 42
```

**SessionFactory.py**:

```
class SessionFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Session

    name = "session"
    foo = 1337
```

**tests.py**:
class TestSession(TestCase):

```
def test_custom_attribute_overwritten_by_factoryboy(self):
    session = SessionFactory.create()
    self.assertEquals(session.foo, 1337)
```

When running the tests I get the following error:

```
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_custom_attribute_overwritten_by_factoryboy (bar.tests.TestSession)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sh4ke/repos/foo/bar/tests.py", line 10, in test_custom_attribute_overwritten_by_factoryboy
    self.assertEquals(session.foo, 1337)
AssertionError: 42 != 1337
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tl;dr

factory_boy can change "custom attributes", (which I assume you mean ones that are *not* django `Fields`), but it can't change read-only attributes, which is what you are trying to do.

### More info

Your problem is that you are trying to use the factory to set an attribute for a read-only property. Roughly, the combination of factory_boy and django means that the call to `SessionFactory()` is doing:

```
session = Session()
session.foo = 1337
```

But I wouldn't expect this to work because unless you declare the `@foo.setter` method `@property` assumes you wanted a read-only property, and so raises attribute error when you attempt to set it.

The weird bit is why you don't see that error, and it turns out that django quietly suppresses it! It sees that your model has the `foo` attribute by doing `getattr(session, 'foo')`, but it has wrapped the whole thing *including the `setattr`* inside a `try: except AttributeError:`, so while it detects and raises an attempt to set an attribute that doesn't exist at all, it also catches and quietly ignores the failed case of an attempt to set a read-only property.

I suspect this is a bug... so will probably try and raise it with the django community.

Comment: I answered the question quite literally, but if what you really want is a way to mock out methods in testing, you should use the `mock` module (`unittest.mock` in python 3) and the `patch` function, which should be able to help you do what you want.